# GraphQL NodeJS Error: One of the provided types for building the Schema is missing a name

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, graphql, graphql-schema

i am learning GraphQL with NodeJS but getting the error.
i have develop a mongoDB and NodeJS GraphQL REST API for Understanding and Learning purpose

[image]

Here is my Code :

```js
const graphql = require('graphql');
const user = require('../models/User');
const post = require('../models/Post');
const { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLID, GraphQLString } = graphql;

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        fname: { type: GraphQLString },
        lname: { type: GraphQLString },
        email: { type: GraphQLString },
        posts: {
            type: PostType,
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    })
});

const PostType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Post',
    fields: () => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        Userid: { type: GraphQLID },
        title: { type: GraphQLString },
        date: { type: GraphQLString },
    })
});

const RootQueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        user: {
            type: UserType,
            args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return user.findById({ id: args.id });
            }
        },
        post: {
            type: PostType,
            args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return post.findById({ id: args.id });
            }
        }
    }
});

module.exports = new graphql.GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQueryType,
});
```

Please Help me to find the Solution.
Answer me to resolve this error.

Comment: it looks like your code can't find the `User` definition (see line `name: 'User'` of your `app.js`). Check you are linking correctly to that `../models/User` and that `User` is indeed defined there.